# Returning an enchantment to your hand

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Krasis Incubation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrasis%20Incubation%5d) has the following ability:

> {1}{G}{U}, Return Krasis Incubation to its owner's hand: Put two +1/+1 counters on enchanted creature.

When Krasis Incubation is being targeted by [Cancel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCancel%5d), can I put it back to my hand to save it?

Comment: Yes krasis incubation

Comment: Please make this question more descriptive.
What does "When you have an enchanted aura is cancelled" mean?
Is there an Aura in play that has another Aura on it? Something got counterspelled (Cancel) or is it being destroyed? Which specific cards are you dealing with?

Comment: like i lay down that card you have a cancell spell

Comment: Are you asking if you can use a "Return <this card> to it's owner's hand" ability on an Aura if the Aura is countered?

Comment: yes i am that is what I'm asking

Answer (score 6):

No.

[Krasis Incubation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrasis%20Incubation%5d)'s ability only functions on the battlefield<sup>[1]</sup>, but [Cancel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCancel%5d) can only target spells, and spells only exist on the stack<sup>[2]</sup>. Therefore, you won't be able to use KI's ability to protect the KI from being countered.

On the other hand, the ability could possibly be used to prevent KI from being destroyed (as opposed to being countered). For example, if your opponent casts [Abolish](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAbolish%5d) targeting KI, you would normally be able to activate KI's ability in response, and this would return KI to your hand before Abolish resolves.

---

1. Generally speaking, if it makes sense for an ability to work when the object on which it resides is on the battlefield, the ability can only be used when the object on which it resides is on the battlefield.<sup>[CR 112.6]</sup>
2. A spell is a card on the stack, a copy of a card on the stack, or a copy of a spell.<sup>[CR 111.1]</sup>

Answer (score 4):

No.

By default, activated abilities on cards only function while those cards are on the battlefield. So if you have an ability such as [Krasis Incubation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKrasis%20Incubation%5d)'s activated ability, you can only activate that ability when the card is on the battlefield. If your spell is countered, then the card never goes to the battlefield.

> 112.6. Abilities of an instant or sorcery spell usually function only while that object is on the stack. Abilities of all other objects usually function **only while that object is on the battlefield**. The exceptions are as follows: *None of the exceptions apply here.*
>
> 701.5a To counter a spell or ability means to cancel it, removing it from the stack. It doesn’t resolve and none of its effects occur. A countered spell is put into its owner’s graveyard.